# Z390 AORUS PRO WIFI "no wifi adapter found" ubuntu 18.04

Tags: networking, wireless, 18.04

I am unable to connect to wifi on ubuntu 18.04LTS. I have used `iwconfig` which returns: eno2, enp0s20f0u9c4i2, and lo, all of which says "no wireless extensions". Running the command `lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net` gives me

```
"Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:a370] (rev 10)
Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device [8086:0034]
Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi"

"Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection (7) I219-V [8086:15bc] (rev 10)
Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd Ethernet Connection (7) I219-V [1458:e000]
Kernel driver in use: e1000e
Kernel modules: e1000e"
```

Can someone please help me regarding this issue. Thank you.

Comment: your wifi driver is loaded properly it seems. perhaps your device is soft or hard blocked. check that with `rfkill list`

Comment: hi Alex, rfkill list gives me:

"0: hci0: Bluetooth
Soft blocked: yes
Hard blocked: no"

Comment: Also, iwconfig now only gives me eno2 and lo. I just plugged an ethernet cable in.

Comment: i have to admit, i am clueless. i found this one here: https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-networking-3/ubuntu-18-04-1-lts-wifi-stopped-working-4175639741/page2.html#post5912798 and this guy here https://forums.tomshardware.com/threads/debian-compatibility-with-wifi-ethernet-on-new-motherboard-gigabyte-z390-aorus-pro.3398003/ and your device ID not listed in here https://wiki.debian.org/iwlwifi#Troubleshooting

Comment: Post results for `dmesg |grep iwl` as you might not have the firmware